# String float to int in python

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, integer

I have the following dataframe:

| data |
| --- |
| A(1.2,2) |
| B(1,5) |
| A(5.8, 9) |
| B(8.9,0.9) |

I would like to convert these float (str) objects to int. How do I do that?

Desired Output:

| data |
| --- |
| A(1,2) |
| B(1,5) |
| A(6, 9) |
| B(9,1) |

What I tried so far?

```
pd.to_numeric(df['data'])
```

But I get the following error: `ValueError: Unable to parse string "A(1,2)" at position 0` How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string and need first to seperate the numbers from each other, propbaly a custom function might be the easiest way:

```
def round_string(s):
    start = s.index('(') +1
    stop = s.index(')')
    l = s[start:stop].split(',')
    lst = [str(int(round(float(i)))) for i in l]
    return s[:start] + ','.join(lst) + s[stop:]

s = "B(8.9,0.9)"
round_string(s)
# 'B(9,1)'
```

---

Map function to dataframe:

```
df['data'].map(round_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your strings are effectively [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).  Treat them as such

- define expected named tuples
- turn into named tuples using `pd.eval()`
- turn back into wanted string representation using f-string
- alternatively use [Series map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to changed to wanted representation

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """df
A(1.2,2)
B(1,5)
A(5.8, 9)
B(8.9,0.9)"""
    ),
    sep="\t",
).rename(columns={"df": "data"})


from collections import namedtuple

A = namedtuple("A", "x y")
B = namedtuple("B", "x y")
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "data": [
            f"{type(nt).__name__}({round(nt.x,0):.0f},{round(nt.y):.0f})"
            for nt in pd.eval(df["data"])
        ]
    }
)
```

#### use `map()` for rounding

```
df["data"] = pd.Series(pd.eval(df["data"])).map(
    lambda nt: str(nt._replace(x=int(round(nt.x, 0)), y=int(round(nt.y, 0))))
)
```

|  | data |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A(1,2) |
| 1 | B(1,5) |
| 2 | A(6,9) |
| 3 | B(9,1) |

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to round off, following should work, replacing the decimal and digits after decimal with empty string

```py
df['data'].str.replace('\.\d+', '', regex=True)
0     A(1,2)
1     B(1,5)
2    A(5, 9)
3     B(8,0)
Name: col, dtype: object
```

For rounding the values, a bit more effort is required, just `extract` the parenthesis part using `regex` and assign it to a temporary column, then use comprehension to round each values calling the `eval` finally replace with new value in the given column.

```py
df.assign(tup=df['data'].str.extract('(\(.*\))')).apply(lambda x: x['data'].replace(x['tup'], str(tuple(round(i) for i in eval(x['tup'])))), axis=1)

0    A(1, 2)
1    B(1, 5)
2    A(6, 9)
3    B(9, 1)
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, when I try to execute it I get an error saying ```SyntaxError: invalid syntax``` Sorry for the silly question, how to I solve it?

Comment: Hello @disukumo, I tested the code twice, and it is running fine on my end with Python 3.7.5 and pandas 1.2.2, One possible reason might be due to pandas older version if you have, another reason might be the sample data you have in the question is different than the actual data you have.

Comment: My python version is 3.8 and pandas is 1.2.4. Not sure, why it isn't working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is convert the floats nested inside of strings into ints.

Furthermore, your output suggests you don't want to use the int function but probably `round(x,0)` (I say this because `int(5.8)` evaluates to `5`, not 6.

So a function like this applied to the dataframe will work:

````
def convert_fn_strs(fn):
    val_list = re.split('[(,)]',fn)
    val_list.remove('')
    fn_name = val_list.pop(0)
    val_list = [round(float(x)) for i,x in enumerate(val_list)]
    return fn_name + str(tuple(val_list))```
````